# What's the best way to stub out network calls with Faraday in the Balanced Ruby client?

Tags: ruby, testing, balanced-payments, faraday

I'm not particularly familiar with Faraday's stubbing API, but from a casual inspection of that and the source of [Balanced::Client](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/blob/master/lib/balanced/client.rb), it looks like I'd need to be able to provide my own value for [`Balanced::Client.conn`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/blob/master/lib/balanced/client.rb#L19).

This is a step towards supporting for a stubbed connection mode by a configuration option in library, whereas flipping on that toggle, I could just use [`Balanced::Client.conn`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/blob/master/lib/balanced/client.rb#L19) as a handle for stubbing whatever requests I expect to occur during my test.

It would also be super useful to have example response bodies for the various Balanced API calls and/or some builtin stub responses to use as templates for my own stubs.

Does this seem like a reasonable plan, or am I heading in the wrong direction? How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a look at how the [unit tests](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/tree/master/spec) for the [balanced-ruby](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby) library are written. They use [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to record and replay network calls.

While not pertinent to your exact question, you can also create one-off instances of objects by using the `construct_from_response` method on any object that inherits from the `Resource` class in `resource.rb`. This allows you to create a single instance of an object like so:

```
1.9.3p194 :034 > payload = {:name"=>"Bob", :uri=>"/v1/marketplaces/M123/accounts/fake"} 
1.9.3p194 :035 > account = Balanced::Account.construct_from_response payload
1.9.3p194 :036 > account.name
 => "Bob"
```

Note that the `uri` param in the payload is required or else the library will go and try to look the object up from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this.  Use the gem `webmock` https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

And stub requests yourself:

```
stub_request(:get,"https://<your secret key>:@api.balancedpayments.com/v1/customers   email=#<test email>")
.with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*',
                   'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3',
                   'User-Agent'=>'balanced-ruby/0.7.4'})
.to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```